# IIS 8.5 Manager: Application Pools and Sites nodes missing

Tags: iis

I've encountered a weird problem that I haven't been able to solve and haven't found any information on: the **Application Pools** and **Sites** nodes in the IIS Manager of our IIS 8.5 went missing!

[image]

This is one of four servers we're running with very similar setup, but it's the only one with Windows Server 2012 R2 and IIS 8.5: we have the default App Pools plus one for our application, and our site and web application which uses our app pool. Everything was running well until Sunday, June 1, 2014, when we received an error message from our monitoring service that our application was unavailable on that server.

We discovered the following entries in the event log:

```
[20:44:24] A worker process '27520' serving application pool 'camping.info' failed to stop a listener channel for protocol 'http' in the allotted time.  The data field contains the error number.
[20:44:24] A process serving application pool 'camping.info' exceeded time limits during shut down. The process id was '27520'.
[20:45:54] A worker process '40744' serving application pool 'camping.info' failed to stop a listener channel for protocol 'http' in the allotted time.  The data field contains the error number.
[20:45:54] A process serving application pool 'camping.info' exceeded time limits during shut down. The process id was '40744'.
[20:45:54] Application pool 'camping.info' is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool.
```

When we RDP'd into the server and looked into the IIS Manager, the **Application Pools** and **Sites** nodes were not visible anymore. Instead, the event log was full of errors like the following (as a result of trying to open the *Server node* below *Start Page*):

```
IISMANAGER_ERROR_LOADING_PROVIDER_TYPE

IIS Manager could not load type 'Microsoft.Web.Management.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModuleProvider, Microsoft.Web.Management.Aspnet, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' for module provider 'SessionState' that is declared in %windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\administration.config. Verify that the type is correct, and that the assembly that contains the module provider is in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC).

Exception:System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Management.Aspnet, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.Web.Management.Aspnet, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
   at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError)
   at Microsoft.Web.Management.Server.AdministrationModuleProvider.GetModuleProvider(String userName, String connectionName)
```

After a few tries with restoring the working iis configuration (C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config\applicationhost.config), we even uninstalled IIS completely and reinstalled it (with some difficulties) but to no avail. Searching for the missing dlls on disk we found that their versions were actually 8.5.*.* so we went ahead and replaced all instances of 8.0.0.0 with 8.5.0.0 in C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config\administration.config but the errors stayed (mentioning 8.0.0.0 still!).

The interesting thing is that our **application is running again** on the server - it's just that we cannot see it in IIS Manager. We'd like to be able to manage it through the GUI and get rid of those errors in the event log.

Any takers?

Answer (score 2):

Finally solved this for my situation:

On Mine seemed to corrupt the applicationhost.config file possibly by msdeploy and/or Visual Studio 2012. Looked ok though. But after a thorough comparison I noticed it was putting the (sites) (/sites) in the wrong place
and the tree view wasn't coming up in IIS Manager.
Moving the sites section back to where in should be did the trick. (just after the (/log) section)

MSdeploy otherwise was working fine just screwed up IIS manager sites view.

Happened to me only on servers where sites were deployed via VS2012 and msdeploy with 2012R2 running IIS8.5

Answer (score 1):

When you uninstall IIS, did you remove everything under `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv`? If not, broken things might remain there.

Comment: No, I didn't do that. I don't feel that I know which files I can safely remove and which not. If I should have to reinstall IIS again, I will try that (after doing a backup). Thanks.

Comment: It seems like the problem lies in the incorrect interpretation of `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config\administration.config` - there the versions are all 8.5.0.0 (except for a few 7's) but the event log messages speak of missing 8.0.0.0 dlls which are indeed missing while the 8.5.0.0 versions are in the GAC.

Comment: There are several possible causes, 1. broken IIS Manager addins; 2. broken IIS installation. Without touching your machine, it is almost impossible to point out what's up. Open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com to consult Microsoft if you like.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the case here, but for a similar situation I encountered on our systems it was simply a case of mismatching versions.

i.e. The server originally creating the shared config was Server 2012 with IIS 8.0, but the server attempting to access it and showing the symptoms displayed mentioned was Server 2012 R2 with IIS 8.5.

Look in the event log after loading IIS Manager and you should see a load of errors indicating it's a missing module problem, likely down to versioning.

Answer (score 1):

For my case, I was working on setting up a new Windows 2019 server to replace my Windows 2012 R2 server.  I started all the feature and role installs for web services and came back to the server later.  I assumed web services were completely installed.

I had a copy of my configuration backup from the old server (Backup-WebConfiguration -Name [backupname], copied from c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\backup\ to new server's backup dir, then ran Restore-WebConfiguration -Name [backupname].)

However, IIS had not been completely installed as a reboot was pending, so I restarted the servers and ensured all features and roles were installed.  When I opened IIS, the Sites section wasn't showing.   Looking in the windows application logs, I found a lot of "IISMANAGER_ERROR_LOADING_PROVIDER_TYPE" errors.

The specific types that were of concern all began with "Microsoft.Web.Management." and were of version 8.5.  The reference to the type was in the c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config\application.config file.

This made me remember that Win 2012R2 uses IIS version 8.5 and the Windows 2019 uses IIS version 10.0.

I went into the application.config file and did a search and replace of 8.5 and switched that to 10.0.

After an IIS reset, my IIS Manager was once again displaying the Application Pools and Sites and all the other features that I expected to see.

I did see some more type errors in the application log, but that was because I hadn't installed an IIS module/add-on on the new server yet.

Also, I did a version comparison of modules in a working Windows Server 2019 application.config and was able to ensure the versions were the same on both.  There were some Microsoft.Web.Management types that were for version 7.0.0.0, as well.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience!

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling IIS from windows components (Control Panel --> Programs & Features).